# Dell T3600 won't start showing amber 3 & 4 with a white power button

Tags: windows-10, acpi, dell-precision

My workstation is a Dell T3600. The 3 & 4 are amber and the power button is white.
Dell's web-site says this is ACPI S3 mode (power saving).  But it won't wake up for anything.
Everything was fine yesterday.  I finished work and left it on like normal.  The screen save turns off after 30 minutes idle.  Windows 10 is configured to not go to sleep or suspend.
Usually just hitting the space bar on the keyboard brings everything back to life.
I've disconnected everything, pulled the ram and reseated it.  Nothing.
As soon as the power is plugged in I can hear the fans and the front displays the same stuff ( 3&4 on, white power button).  After a about 30 seconds I see the hard drive indicator flicker and then nothing.  Nothing is displayed on the screen.  No combination of keys does anything.

And suggestions?

Comment: Disconnect hard drive and power up, is behavior different?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely faulty memory.

A quick look round the net says this is most likely faulty memory.

While I couldn't find anythign specific to your model - the T5600 and T7600 seend to suffer from an alarming amount of failures according to the Dell forums.

Rip all the memory out, add a single stick back in and boot.  if it works, add another... and another until you find the culprit.  Worst case (if you're careful)  - you waste a bit of time and go back to the drawing board.

Comment: thanks.  I'll give that a shot this weekend.  Im also going to call Dell to see if they have a different meaning for those lights.  Sadly I'm slammed with work so I migrated to my laptops for now.